# Problemas para deserializar JSON en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema al momento de deserializar una respuesta JSON.

Tengo mi cadena JSON (Esto es un response que me arroja mi aplicación tercera, un mensaje de inserción satisfactorio).

```
{"data":[{"code":"SUCCESS","details":{"Modified_Time":"2019-10-04T14:04:48-05:00","Modified_By":{"name":"Jonathan Brin","id":"862577000033848326"},"Created_Time":"2019-10-04T14:04:48-05:00","id":"862577000226166843","Created_By":{"name":"Jonathan Brin","id":"862577000033848326"}},"message":"record added","status":"success"}]}
```

utilice Json2csharp.com para poder generar las clases a partir de esa respuesta.

```
class extraccion_Newton
{
    public class ModifiedBy
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreatedBy
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public static DateTime Modified_Time { get; set; }
        public static ModifiedBy Modified_By { get; set; }
        public static DateTime Created_Time { get; set; }
        public static string id { get; set; }
        public static CreatedBy Created_By { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public Details details { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Luego trato de deserializarlo, utilice de la libreria NewtonSoft, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me aparece vació:

un ejemplo de mi clase principal

```
 Client = new RestClient("https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Accesorios");
        Respuesta = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        Respuesta.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("content-length", "597");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("cookie", "6726760df9=e25bda1740285ed46e44d68b0d69a635; crmcsr=ff8f1992-0341-42ec-9b65-ce80c1027fe8; JSESSIONID=F20B02759EEB76E2A424A092BCAAF7D1");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Host", "www.zohoapis.com");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "dacb3086-e00d-4620-a82c-0e38e4f1636c,e53a75da-4aa4-4db1-8a11-e9d0fa45fb52");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Type", "OAuth 2.0");
        Respuesta.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
        Respuesta.AddParameter("Created", "{\n\t\"data\": [\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"Owner\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"id\": \"862577000033848326\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t    \"Moneda\": \"" + Moneda + "\",\n\t\t    \"Descripci_n\": \"" + Descripcion1 + "\",\n\t\t    \"Name\": \"" + Descripcion1 + "\",\n\t\t    \"C_digo_Fabricante\": \"" + Codigo + "\",\n\t\t    \"Categor_a_Accesorio\": \"" + Categoria + "\",\n\t\t    \"Pais\": \"" + Pais + "\",\n\t\t    \"Precio_Accesorio\": " + Precio + ",\n\t\t    \"Fabricante\": \"" + Fabricante + "\",\n\t\t    \"Tipo_Accesorio\": \"" + Categoria + "\",\n\t\t    \"Origen_del_Accesorio\": \"" + OrigenPais + "\",\n\t\t    \"Proveedor_Por_Omisi_n\": \"" + Fabricante + "\",\n\t\t    \"IVA\": " + Impuesto1 + ",\n\t\t    \"Modelo\": \"" + Modelo + "\",\n\t\t    \"Almac_n\": \"" + Almacen + "\",\n\t\t    \"Cantidad_Disponibles\": \"" + Disponible + "\"\n\t\t}\n\t]\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(Respuesta);


        extraccion_Newton extr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<extraccion_Newton>(response.Content);
```

Necesito esta ayuda urgente
Saludos

Comment: Podrias poner el JSON como texto y no como imagen y mostrarnos lo que haz intentado?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, por favor indica la cadena JSON en texto, no en imagen.

Comment: Claro, lo lamento. {"data":[{"code":"SUCCESS","details":{"Modified_Time":"2019-10-04T14:04:48-05:00","Modified_By":{"name":"Jonathan Brin","id":"862577000033848326"},"Created_Time":"2019-10-04T14:04:48-05:00","id":"862577000226166843","Created_By":{"name":"Jonathan Brin","id":"862577000033848326"}},"message":"record added","status":"success"}]}  tengo una clase creada a partir de este Json

Comment: @JRaul porfavor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/298528/edit) tu pregunta y añadí el código ahí

Comment: Listo @JuanSalvadorPortugal, Aqui esta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los pasos que mencionas estan correctos, pero no entiendo porque deserializas al nombre  `extraccion_Newton` cuando debes usar el nombre de la class `RootObject`

Cambia donde dice

```
class extraccion_Newton
```

por

```
namespace extraccion_Newton
```

si encapsulas todo dentro de otra clase adicionas un nivel mas en el objeto que no necesitas

Entonces el codigo quedaria

```
RootObject extr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
```

entiendo que el string que nos mencionas lo obtienes desde el `response.Content`

Comment: Vale gracias por el comentario, realice los cambios precisos, pero ahora me aparece un error dentro del foreach para obtener el dato, dice: "No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo "extraccion_Newton.Details", lo tengo formulado de la siguiente manera: `foreach(Datum d in extrRo.data) { Details dt = d.details;}`

Comment: habria que ver si ese Details que usas para definir `dt` es el mismo que se deserializa, que pasa si usas `var dt = d.details;` podrias poner un breakpoint he inspeccionar que tipo esta tomando `dt`

Answer (score 0):

No seria?

```
extraccion_Newton extr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
```

Si usas NewtonSoft podrias usar la clase dynamic:

```
dynamic extr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

Le podes agregar la codificacion si hace falta.